Homeomorphism between Compact and hausdorff then $\overline{f(A)}=f(\overline{A})$ for all $A\subseteq X$
I have been trying to prove this, in class we discused the first part, so I know that $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{(f(A))}$ holds, but I am not sure about the other part, could someone correct my proof or give some advice, please?
Let $X,Y \in (Top)_0$ with $X$ compact and $Y$ Hausdorff. If $f \in Hom_{Top}(X,Y)$, then $\overline{f(A)}=f(\overline{A})$ for all $A\subseteq X$.
For this proof, we will verify the double containment, using the following results:
If $X,Y \in (Top)_0$, $X$ compact, $Y$ Hausdorff, and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$, the following conditions are equivalent:
$f$ is continuous
$f(\bar A)\subseteq \overline{(f(A))}$ for all $A \subseteq X$
$f^{-1}(z)$ is closed in $X$ for every closed $z$ in $Y$.
and the properties of continuous functions.
By hypothesis, $f$ is continuous, by the equivalence stated above, we know that $f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{(f(A))}$ holds.
Let $A \subseteq X$ such that $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is compact, hence $f(A)$ is compact and since $Y$ is Hausdorff, $f(A)$ is closed.
Now let's see that if $B \subseteq Y$ is closed in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$. As $B$ is closed $B=\overline{B}$, it suffices to show that $\overline{f^{-1}(B)}\subseteq f^{-1}(\overline{B})$, and remember that by hypothesis $f$ is a homeomorphism, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous, then:
$$f(x)\in f(\overline{f^{-1}(B)}) \subseteq \overline{f({f^{-1}(B)})}$$ This is because we know that $f(\bar A)\subseteq \overline{(f(A))}$ holds and since $B=\overline{B}$, we have:
$$x \in f^{-1}(f(x))\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$$

Your $f$ is not a homeomorphism. $Hom_{Top}$ is not the set of all homeomorphisms, it is all continuous maps.

I see, I tried this proof:

By the definition of closure, $A \subseteq \overline{A}=A \cup A'$, and since $f$ is continuous, $f(A) \subseteq f(\overline{A})$. Additionally, as mentioned in the second property, the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact, and the image of a compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed. Therefore, $f(\overline{A})$ is a closed set in $Y$.
Since $f(A) \subseteq f(\overline{A})$, we have $\overline{f(A)} \subseteq \overline{f(\overline{A})}$. But $f(\overline{A})$ is closed, hence $\overline{f(A)} \subseteq f(\overline{A})$.
We conclude that $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$ for every $A \subseteq X$.
